# Battling over- underflow of Encoder interface timer STM32 (Nucleof303RE)

Tags: c++, timer, stm32, stm32f4discovery, nucleo

Im writing code for a rotary encoder, and im trying to use the encoder feature in the general purpose timers. This works, to a certain extend. The CNT register resets to ARR value when the downcounter is triggered when CNT == 0;

In other words: The counter doesnt stop downcounting at zero, it plops to the ARR value instead. I want to make it so that the counter stays at zero, even if the rotary encoder is turned counter clockwise (which would normally decrease the value). Ultimately, i would like the counter to not reload when hitting the ARR value too, but rather stay there. But thats a next step.

I feel like there are settings in the datasheet that would enable me to achieve this, however after hours i cannot seem to find them. Below is my code for initializing the rotary encoder. Its clock pin is connected to pa0 and its dt pin to pa1. The value of CNT is printed in the main loop.

```
    void encoder_init(uint32_t max_value)
 {
RCC->AHBENR|=RCC_AHBENR_GPIOAEN;
RCC->APB1ENR|=RCC_APB1ENR_TIM2EN;
GPIOA->MODER|=(1<<1)|(1<<3);
GPIOA->AFR[0]|=(1<<0)|(1<<4);
TIM2->ARR = max_value;
TIM2->CCMR1 |= (TIM_CCMR1_CC1S_0 | TIM_CCMR1_CC2S_0 ); 
TIM2->CCER &= ~(TIM_CCER_CC1P | TIM_CCER_CC2P);  
TIM2->SMCR |= TIM_SMCR_SMS_0 | TIM_SMCR_SMS_1;   
TIM2->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_CEN ;   
}
```

Edit: Refrence manual: https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00043574-stm32f303xb-c-d-e-stm32f303x6-8-stm32f328x8-stm32f358xc-stm32f398xe-advanced-arm-based-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf

Comment: Can you provide the datasheet?

Comment: @paddy i have updated the question to include the refrence manual we use to determine certain actions.